# Is there a hotkey in visual studio code that takes you outside of a pair of quotation marks?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-editor

`<div class="text|"` if the | represents my cursor - Is there a way to move outside of the quotation marks quickly aside from the right arrow, or actually grabbing my mouse and moving the cursor? There was a feature like this in pycharm and it was super nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SHIFT` + `"`.

This does not affect your typing flow and works. It only works if you haven't left the quotation marks before.

Comment: Any idea what this shortcut is called? Also, any idea if there are equivalents for things like parenthesis/curly brackets?

Comment: I do not know what it is called. For parenthesis or curly braces it is the same thing, as long as you have not left the brackets before. Use `)` and `}` respectively.

Comment: thought I tried that but I guess not, thank you. Also just out of curiosity; how did you figure that out?

Comment: I figured it out through trial and error. I thought I had answered you back then but it seems the message was never sent,

Answer (score 0):

if on macbook `cmd+right arrow` will go to the end of the line and `alt+right arrow` will go to the end of closing tag `>`
I believe on windows just `ctrl+ right` will work

Comment: Yeah just pressing the right arrow moves you over. Being able to use tab was super nice though because you didn't have to stretch your finger over to hit the right arrow. Tab is right next to where my fingers are positioned while typing. It's a small gripe, but I just figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by). And use the Move By function by defining a keybinding that searches for the nearest quote and place the cursor after that. Maybe you need to put the quote in a look behind group.